Can faded or peeling clearcoat be "repaired" without a doing a full paint job?
As the subject states, is there a reasonable or feasible way to repair failed clearcoat? In the context of a 10+ year old used car, a proper repaint is often price prohibitive. This is an example of the condition I am referring to (shown on a 2010 Honda Accord):

To be clear, I am asking for either a DIY method, of even if a professional shop has repair methods short of a full repaint.
